# Selenium in Python not finding any elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have written numerous scripts to scrape websites. I am looking to scrape games and odds from [here](https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/navigation/nba)

I am not able to find any elements at all. I have looked for almost all the `div` items, but tried root, and it didn't work.

The code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Location\\chromedriver',options=options)

driver.get('https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/navigation/nba')
time.sleep(20)
events = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[id="root"]')
```

I am able to find the root item. But I am unable to find other elements:
For example, the games are contained in a `div` with the classes `ae aj im s h i j ak l m al o am q an`.

Added this line of code:

```py
events = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="ae aj im s h i j ak l m al o am q an"]')
```

But the `events` variable is empty: `[]`

Comment: What error is returned?

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[id="root"]"}), I have tested with other divs, with a find_elements, and the list comes up blank

Comment: What are you expecting the last line to do?

Comment: Honestly, finding anything within the page. I have been unable to pull other divs or spans

Comment: How will you know when it finds something? You could try `print(events.text) `

Comment: @Sportsworkstation - just curious if you ever found a solution to this? I am trying scrape the site myself too and running into a lot of issues because of their dynamic class names.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prefix attributes with @. So, the following should work

`events = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="root"]')`

Comment: This worked, thank you. Appreciate the prompt response.

Comment: @Sportsworkstation Happy to help!